# weakref module has no attribute 'weakvaluedictionary'

Tags: python, python-2.7, weak-references, python-module

There came up strange error from python today. Whatever i want to launch or do, i can't getting error : 'module' has no attribute 'weakvaluedictionary'.
Even tried to launch pip install/uninstall and got same error.
Nothing has been changed from last day, and yesterday everything was working perfectly.
I checked  *init*.py and did not see anything strange with weakref:
there is `import weakref` and `_handlers = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()  #map of handler names to handlers` lines.
Please help!!

Comment: how are you trying to import `WeakValueDictionary`?

Comment: Did you call any module / package in your python path `weakref`?

Comment: Jim, i am not importing weakvaluedictionary() itself, calling:_handlers = weakref.WeakValueDictionary(). But it is line in pip site -package _init_.py file, i haven't changed it

Comment: You should import `weakref` in interactive mode and see if the problem exists there as well (call `weakref.WeakValueDictionary()`). If it does, just type `weakref` to see where the module is imported from and if that is the right file.

Comment: Klaus, could you specify a bit how that 'interactive mode' should look like?

Comment: Klaus, i went to cmd, entered `python` , then  `import weakref`  then `weakref.WeakValueDictionary()`  and got same error

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure you haven't maybe created a custom python file named `weakref`?

Comment: No , Jim, I didn't. Should weakref have a folder in lib->site packages? I do not find it in it

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue than you. The problem was that I was naming the file I was trying to run/edit as weakref.py  Then, only change the name. I changed name to "weakref_example.py"